# ExtJS Grid or Telerik MVC Grid: Bind only updated/changed data (per cell)

Tags: jquery, data-binding, extjs, jqgrid, telerik-grid

I need to update the data displayed in the grid every second.

I use jQuery to make an ajax call every second and then I need to bind the data in the grid, but only change the specific cells that changed/updated.

I know that when using Telerik MVC Grid, when I call their 'dataBind' function, all the `<tbody>` is changed.

It is possible to change only the data updated/changed using Telerik or ExtJS grids?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.
ExtJS grids are always backed by 'store's that hold records (think record - grid row data)
Once you get data back from the server, if you can identify the changes by the some id field, you can locate the particular record from the store, change its field values (mapped to cells) that you want to change, and commit the record to update the particular cells.

Off course, its easier to just use [Ext.Direct](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect) stack but I understand it may not always be possible in already existing projects.